# Filter Multidimensional Array with Another Array Values - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a parent, child array and i have to filter the array with child ID array,

Array to filter:

```
var Array = [
    {
        "parent_ID": "1",
        "children" : [
            {
                "child_id": "1",
                "name": "Bench",
                "parent_ID": "1",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "2",
                "name": "Back Squat",
                "parent_ID": "1",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "parent_ID": "2",
        "children" : [
            {
                "child_id": "3",
                "name": "Mathew",
                "parent_ID": "2",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "4",
                "name": "Jeeva",
                "parent_ID": "2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "parent_ID": "3",
        "children" : [
            {
                "child_id": "5",
                "name": "Fran",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "6",
                "name": "Francis",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "7",
                "name": "Tom",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "8",
                "name": "Jack",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            }
        ]
       
    }
];
```

Array to filter with:

```
var ChildIDs = ['1', '8', '5']
```

Expected Array

```
var ExpectedArray = [
    {
        "parent_ID": "1",
        "children" : [
            {
                "child_id": "1",
                "name": "Bench",
                "parent_ID": "1",
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        "parent_ID": "3",
        "children" : [
            {
                "child_id": "5",
                "name": "Fran",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            },
            {
                "child_id": "8",
                "name": "Jack",
                "parent_ID": "3",
            }
        ]
       
    }
];
```

Please help ....................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You can't, because your original data structure is invalid. You're missing object key after `"parent_ID": "1",` (you have directly another `{`). Simply entering this code in the console gives : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`. For that matter, the expected output structure is invalid too. Javascript just can't work with that.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the issue, and i have fixed and updated the question.